# C# : How to add item into list

Tags: c#, list

I want to add items into a list. The items are obtained from database.
How to do that?

```
List<sp_Random_Question_Result> questionList=new List<sp_Random_Question_Result>();

questionList=  QuestionDataService.GetRandomQuestion(3, "A");
questionList= QuestionDataService.GetRandomQuestion(3, "B");
questionList = QuestionDataService.GetRandomQuestion(3, "C");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Share your class of `sp_Random_Question_Result`

Comment: You could try to search for "C# how to add item to a list", and you will get this useful documentation link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the `Add()` method.

`questionList.Add(QuestionDataService.GetRandomQuestion(3, "A"));`
`questionList.Add(QuestionDataService.GetRandomQuestion(3, "B"));`
`questionList.Add(QuestionDataService.GetRandomQuestion(3, "C");)`

Comment: There is an error when use .add() function. I think there is a wrong pattern.

Comment: @TimothyVarian Is Output of `QuestionDataService.GetRandomQuestion(3, "A");` an instance of `sp_Random_Question_Result`? What error did you get?

Comment: It's a row of table that contain of 8 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of type sp_Random_Question_Result like

```
sp_Random_Question_Result resulrObject=new sp_Random_Question_Result();
resulrObject.value1="Some Value1";
resulrObject.value2="Some Value2";
questionList.Add(resulrObject);
```

You can also do like

```
questionList.Add(new sp_Random_Question_Result {
value1="Some Value1",
value2="Some Value2"
});
```